# TypeError: Cannot read property 'process' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, frontend

I have such a code problem

What is best practice?
Thanks

Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'process' of undefined

**myComponent.ts**

```
  ProcessInfo: any | false;


  showSaveItems = () => {
    this.typeCategory = [];
    this.dataTypesLoop = [];

    if (this.ProcessInfo.process.data.mortgage.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.ProcessInfo.process.data.mortgage.length; i++) {
        if (this.ProcessInfo.process.data.mortgage[i].mortgageHeader !== null) {
          const findItem = this.categories.find(
            obj =>
              obj.value ==
              this.ProcessInfo.process.data.mortgage[i].mortgageHeader.category
          );

        }
      }
    }

    this.dataTypes = new Set(this.dataTypesLoop);
    return new Set(this.typeCategory);
  };
```

**myComponent.html**

```
  <li *ngFor="let item of showSaveItems()">
       <strong>{{ item.text }}</strong>
   </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the path exists

```
 if (this.ProcessInfo && this.ProcessInfo.process && this.ProcessInfo.process.data && this.ProcessInfo.process.data.mortgage && this.ProcessInfo.process.data.mortgage.length>0) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply

there are many such codes.

Looking for another best practice :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to instantiate your parameter before to use it:

```
  ProcessInfo: any | false = false;
```

using '**:**' you just set his type, but his value is 'undefined' until you use '**=**';

the, to use process parameter of your object, need to verify if exist:

```
if (this.ProcessInfo.hasOwnProperty('process')) {
  if (this.ProcessInfo.process.data.mortgage.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.ProcessInfo.process.data.mortgage.length; i++) {
        if (this.ProcessInfo.process.data.mortgage[i].mortgageHeader !== null) {
          const findItem = this.categories.find(
            obj =>
              obj.value ==
              this.ProcessInfo.process.data.mortgage[i].mortgageHeader.category
          );

        }
      }
   }
}
```